# PYTHON - Como passar um parâmetro?

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu estou tentando montar o jogo da cobrinha usando python, porém eu me deparei com um problema que travou completamente meu código.
Eu utilizei a biblioteca tkinter e todas as suas funções para criar o jogo, segue o código:

```
import tkinter
import random
from time import sleep

window = tkinter.Tk()

width = 800
height = 600

#FUNÇÃO QUE CRIA O MAPA

def Create_map(width, height):
    mapa = tkinter.Canvas(width= width, height= height, bg='black')
    mapa.pack()
    coordenadas = [10,10]
    Create_snake(coordenadas, mapa)
    Create_fruits(coordenadas, mapa, width, height)


#FUNÇÃO QUE CRIA A COBRA
def Create_snake(coordenadas, mapa):
    coordenadas = coordenadas
    snake = mapa.create_rectangle(coordenadas, 30, 30, fill='white')
    window.bind("<Up>", Move_Up)
    window.bind("<Down>", Move_Down)
    window.bind("<Left>", Move_Left)
    window.bind("<Right>", Move_Right)




#FUNÇÃO QUE CRIA AS FRUTAS
def Create_fruits(coordenadas, mapa, width, height):
    newcoord = [random.randint(10, width - 30), random.randint(10, height - 30)]
    fruits = mapa.create_rectangle(newcoord, newcoord[0] + 20, newcoord[1] + 20, fill='pink')



#FUNÇÃO QUE MOVE A COBRA
def Move_Up(key):
    print(key)

def Move_Down(key):
    print(key)


def Move_Left(key):
    print(key)

def Move_Right(key):
    print(key)







Create_map(width, height)

window.mainloop()
```

Eu estou usando as funções Move_Up, _Down, _Left  e _Right para atualizar a posição da cobra, porém ao utilizar o bind() eu não consigo passar nenhum parâmetro para as funções, ou seja, eu não tenho acesso ao widget snake para atualizar a coordenada e, logo, atualizar a posição da cobra. Alguém tem ideia do que fazer para passar o parâmetro nas funções que tem Move??

Comment: Ao usar funções, você pode deixar o objeto `snake` como global, já que precisará atualizá-lo de diversas funções; mas pode gerenciar esse escopo também utilizando uma classe.

Comment: Gerenciar o escopo utilizando uma classe? Alguma referência ou link de como fazer isso? Obrigado!!!

Comment: Para executar funções você deve escreve-las da forma `foo()`, do contrário a função não executará. Tente:

```
def foo(s):
    return (s)
print(foo)
print(foo(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é criar uma função que chama a sua outra função; assim o parâmetro que você quer passar será capturado pelo escopo da função (conhecido como *closure*):

```
snake = mapa.create_rectangle(coordenadas, 30, 30, fill='white')
def chama_move_up()
    Move_Up(snake)
window.bind("<Up>", chama_move_up)


def Move_Up(s):
    # .... s é a snake ....
```

Uma outra solução é usar classes, e colocar esses objetos como atributos de instância `self`; assim eles são acessíveis em qualquer método da classe:

```
class Jogo:
    # ....
    def create_snake(self, coordenadas, mapa):
        self.snake = mapa.create_rectangle(coordenadas, 30, 30, fill='white')
        window.bind("<Up>", self.move_up)
        ...

    def move_up(self):
        # aqui pode usar self.snake
```

Answer (score -1):

Então, sei que já tem muito tempo, mas vou deixar a explicação, pois pode ajudar outras pessoas...

Você consegue passar as parâmetros utilizando o lambda:

```
# Função que executa o .bind
def Executa_a_funcao(event, parametro): #event é o evento automático
    print(f'O evento foi {event}')
    print(f'O parâmetro foi {parametro}')

#chamada da função:
widget.bind("<Up>", lambda event, parametro = 'seu parâmetro':  Executa_a_funcao(event, parametro))
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).